# user-new.php less detailed after WP3.1; how to revert?

Tags: admin, customization, users, multisite, profiles

I updated WP to 3.1, and one issue my organization (which uses WP in Network Mode) is having is the Add New User page in wp-admin is now much less detailed -- before it was more like profile.php, with the ability to set username, password and much more. Now, it's only username, password and role.

Any idea how to revert this back? Our organization generally creates accounts for people instead of vice-versa?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm running 3.1.2 I got Username, First Name, Last Name, Website, Password, Send Password and Role. Did I missunderstand your question?

Comment: @Kovshenin Are you running WP's Network Mode? I should have mentioned that...

Answer (score 1):

The old user registration form is not compatible with the new one due to the new multi site user roles introduced.

While it does involve an extra step the new users profile can be edited once the user is created.

There are also plugins available that extend the add new user options.

Gravity Forms has a [user registration add on](http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/) that allows you to customize a user registration form and WPMUdev.org has a [Add New User plugin](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/add-new-users) that extends the form in admin.

Comment: Ugh -- so you're saying the way that WP Network Mode now creates users, all of the usermeta (I.e., display name, website, bio etc.) is now configured on a per-site basis, and that I can't set a user's, say, bio info globally on a network-wide basis? That is so, so, so weak...

Re: your suggestions -- I have no idea what the first plugin looks like since it costs money and has no screenshots, while the second one has none of the fields I'm actually needing and seems like it's ultimately just a batch version of the regular user-new.php.

Answer (score 0):

No you should be able to create the user and edit the user on a network basis not site basis at least that is how it shows on mine.

Comment: one other thing if you want to add more fields to your signup pages just add it to your themes function page or create a simple plugin and post it in /wp-content/mu-plugins